# $(\mathbb Z_6,+)$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations that is a subgroup of $S_n$ for some $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism

Here is my question :

> Find $n$ such that $(\mathbb Z_6,+)$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations that is a subgroup of $S_n$.

I thought the answer would be $S_3$ but it turns out that $S_3$ is not abelian. Now I'm completely lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that they are asking you to show an isomorphism with a _subgroup_ of a symmetric group. Hint: $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is sometimes called a _cyclic_ group.

Comment: Do you know Cayley's theorem, that every finite group is isomorphic to a permutation group? Do you know the proof of Cayley's theorem? Do you kinow how to find the order of a permutation? Can you find an element of order $6$ in $S_6$ In $S_5$?

Comment: The question has been answered - look [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111119125824AA64MYc).

Answer (score 3):

Since $(\mathbb Z_6,+)$ is a cyclic group of order $6$, you need to find an element of order $6$ in $S_n$.

$S_3$ does not have an element of order $6$.
Nor does $S_4$.

$S_6$ clearly does: the $6$-cycle $(123456)$.

Perhaps surprisingly, so does $S_5$, even though it's not a $6$-cycle: $(12)(345)$.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A008475.